# TypeError: this._chipList.registerInput is not a function - Angular Material

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

**Problem Statement**

I am trying to get the input from an `<input>` tag and display it as chips in the GUI, but the console gives me the error: `"TypeError: this._chipList.registerInput is not a function"`.

---

**Code**

```
<mat-form-field>
<h3 class="sizeHeading">Add a size</h3>
<input matInput [matChipInputFor]="sizes" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addSize($event)" <= Crash happens here
[(ngModel)]="data.size" class="sizeInput"><br><br>
</mat-form-field>

.... <!-- More code here but it is not part of the problem and what I am trying to show -->

<!-- Sizes display as chips -->
<div *ngIf="!displayOptions">
<mat-chip-list>
<mat-chip #sizes *ngFor="let size of sizes" [removable]="removable"
(removed)="removeSize(size)">
{{size}}
<mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
</div>
```

---

**Explanation of Code**

In the top block of HTML code, I am trying to get user input and display it as chips in the GUI, and that is done in the bottom block of HTML code.

As you can see, and I think this is the problem but I am not sure, is that the `[matChipInputFor]="sizes"` in the input tag is supposed to point to the `#sizes` element in the bottom block of code to show where to output the input. And indeed, the line where the program crashes is the line of code where I specify `[matChipInputFor]="sizes"` in the input tag.

---

**What I've tried**

- I have Googled and it seems that this error is not showing up in the results or anywhere on Stackover Flow.
- I have tried placing the top block of code within the `div` tag with the `*ngIf` condition but to no avail. I did this because I thought that maybe this is a problem with the scope of the `#sizes` element.

---

**Actual Results**

The program crashes with the error, `"TypeError: this._chipList.registerInput is not a function"` and I cannot take the input and display it as chips.

---

**Expected Results**

I want to take the input and display it as chips in Angular Material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1. The #sizes reference attribute is conflicting with your sizes array. You could name it #sizeList, for example.
2. The [matChipInputFor] reference has to point to the chip list (mat-chip-list), not the chips themselves. So you should move the #sizeList to your mat-chip-list element.

So it should look something like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matChipInputFor]="sizeList" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addSize($event)" [(ngModel)]="data.size" class="sizeInput"><br><br>
</mat-form-field>

<div *ngIf="!displayOptions">
  <mat-chip-list #sizeList>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let size of sizes" [removable]="removable" (removed)="removeSize(size)">
      {{size}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation of what I did wrong.